# Check that local machine dependencies for macOS application exist

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Having an issue with my app crashing if a local dependency is missing. I'm building a macOS application -- using Swift 5 in Xcode -- that uses a library, which then wraps a C++ library (`librdkafka`). If I install `librdkafka` using `homebrew` everything works as expected with no issues.

If I uninstall `librdkafka` however, the application crashes before even opening, and a window is displayed explaining why it crashed: because it cannot find `librdkafka` (as expected since I purposefully uninstalled `librdkafka`)

[image]

I understand why this is crashing, but what I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to *gracefully* handle the scenario where `librdkafka` does not exist on the local machine?

I implemented a function to check the file itself exists and I call it in `applicationWillFinishLaunching` in the delegate, but the app crashes before that function is called, so thats no good.

My second thought would be to maybe fork the repo and tweak the imports here: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/SwiftKafka/blob/master/Sources/Crdkafka/shim.h -- but I am not 100% sure if this is the best way.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the application sandboxed?

Comment: @ElTomato The application is not currently sandboxed. I do have `Hardened Runtime` enabled & also selected `Disable library validation`